# Case statement crashing model sim

Tags: verilog, modelsim, quartus

I'm reasonably new to ModelSim and Quartus and for the university I need to make an HDMI controller over an I²C interface. I am rewriting some given code into my own version of an HDMI I²C interface. In the given code, I'm given the following always block.

When running the design in ModelSim, using that case statement in the always block causes ModelSim to crash. I can see something about an out of memory error before it closes (can't find error logs anywhere).

The given code does work when tested on a real board. And in my version, synthesizes and compiles fine. (I can't test the given project in ModelSim as it gets other errors.)

I can provide more segments of code as needed, however it is the segment alone that causes the crash. (I tried with the other blocks there or commented out. Still crashes.)

```
reg [15:0]  LUT_DATA; 
reg [6:0]       LUT_INDEX;
parameter       LUT_SIZE = 31;
...
always
begin
case(LUT_INDEX) 
//  Video Config Data
0   :   LUT_DATA    <=  16'h9803;  //Must be set to 0x03 for proper operation
1   :   LUT_DATA    <=  16'h0100;  //Set 'N' value at 6144
2   :   LUT_DATA    <=  16'h0218;  //Set 'N' value at 6144
3   :   LUT_DATA    <=  16'h0300;  //Set 'N' value at 6144
4   :   LUT_DATA    <=  16'h1470;  // Set Ch count in the channel status to 8.
5   :   LUT_DATA    <=  16'h1520;  //Input 444 (RGB or YCrCb) with Separate Syncs, 48kHz fs
6   :   LUT_DATA    <=  16'h1630;  //Output format 444, 24-bit input
7   :   LUT_DATA    <=  16'h1846;  //Disable CSC
8   :   LUT_DATA    <=  16'h4080;  //General control packet enable
9   :   LUT_DATA    <=  16'h4110;  //Power down control
10  :   LUT_DATA    <=  16'h49A8;  //Set dither mode - 12-to-10 bit
11  :   LUT_DATA    <=  16'h5510;  //Set RGB in AVI infoframe
12  :   LUT_DATA    <=  16'h5608;  //Set active format aspect
13  :   LUT_DATA    <=  16'h96F6;  //Set interrup
14  :   LUT_DATA    <=  16'h7307;  //Info frame Ch count to 8
15  :   LUT_DATA    <=  16'h761f;  //Set speaker allocation for 8 channels
16  :   LUT_DATA    <=  16'h9803;  //Must be set to 0x03 for proper operation
17  :   LUT_DATA    <=  16'h9902;  //Must be set to Default Value
18  :   LUT_DATA    <=  16'h9ae0;  //Must be set to 0b1110000
19  :   LUT_DATA    <=  16'h9c30;  //PLL filter R1 value
20  :   LUT_DATA    <=  16'h9d61;  //Set clock divide
21  :   LUT_DATA    <=  16'ha2a4;  //Must be set to 0xA4 for proper operation
22  :   LUT_DATA    <=  16'ha3a4;  //Must be set to 0xA4 for proper operation
23  :   LUT_DATA    <=  16'ha504;  //Must be set to Default Value
24  :   LUT_DATA    <=  16'hab40;  //Must be set to Default Value
25  :   LUT_DATA    <=  16'haf16;  //Select HDMI mode
26  :   LUT_DATA    <=  16'hba60;  //No clock delay
27  :   LUT_DATA    <=  16'hd1ff;  //Must be set to Default Value
28  :   LUT_DATA    <=  16'hde10;  //Must be set to Default for proper operation
29  :   LUT_DATA    <=  16'he460;  //Must be set to Default Value
30  :   LUT_DATA    <=  16'hfa7d;  //Nbr of times to look for good phase

default:        LUT_DATA    <=  16'h9803;
endcase
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You're more likely to get a useful answer if you follow the guidelines [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Secondly, provide something executable so that someone else can easily see what you're seeing. Finally, just supply the minimum code required to reproduce the problem. These last two are called an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Get rid of the "other errors" first

Comment: `always` always what? Try e.g. always @ ( * )

Answer (score 0):

Yep @Oldfarts comment worked! I had to add the @(*). thank you! I spent so long trying to figure out what was wrong. You would think that something like that would be picked up by either the Quartus or ModelSim complier.